# how to call javascript function in ejs template?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have a javascript function defined under  in ejs template
and would like to call this function when form is submitted

But it is not calling checkPassword function.

Is there anything I missed here?

```
register.ejs

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkPassword() 
        {
            console.log("=============");
            const password = document.getElementsByName('password').value;
            console.log(password);
            console.log(form);
            return true;
        }
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <form  onSubmit="return checkPassword()">
    ... <-- get password and password confirm input
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info mt-4">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: It probably is. Do you want to return `false` instead? That will avoid the form to submit itself.

Comment: why do u return on submit?

Comment: do u even catch the returned value? `true` or `false`?